# "Could not find gem" of a Rails engine gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby

I have a Rails 3.2 Engine (mountable) called "Backend".

The Ruby platform is JRuby 1.7.0 (1.9.3p203).

I also have a Rails 3.2 application (called my_app), where the Gemfile contain:

```
gem 'backend', :path => "/home/jacob/projects/backend"
```

I execute "bundle install" at the root directory of my_app and get the following error:

**"Could not find gem 'backend (>= 0) java' in source at /home/jacob/projects/backend.
Source does not contain any versions of 'backend (>= 0) java'"**

The backend.gemspec:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", \__FILE__)  
require "backend/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|  
  s.name        = "Backend"  
  s.version     = Backend::VERSION  
  s.authors     = [""]  
  s.email       = [""]  
  s.homepage    = ""  
  s.summary     = ""  
  s.description = ""  

  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/\**/*"] + ["MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
  s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the gem name is case-sensitive. Try

```
s.name = "backend"
```

in your gemspec, or

```
gem "Backend", , :path => "/home/jacob/projects/backend"
```

in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Probably an error coming from the dependency on jruby-openssl

Comment: I've just removed all "add_dependency" and error is still there.